# Shortening flight number regex

Tags: regex

I'm making a regex to match all valid international flight numbers, as well as flight codes. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_number), a valid flight code is in the format `XX(a)NNNN(a)`, where `X = [A-Za-z0-9]`, `a = [A-Za-z]`, and `N = [0-9]`.

Since I want to match both flight codes and numbers, I made the `XX(a)` and `(a)` optional. The first `(a)` is completely optional, but the first two `XX` must be present for the `(a)` to match if present. I made the following regex, but I want to shorten it if possible.

`^(([A-Za-z0-9]{2}([A-Za-z])?)?)([0-9]{4})(([A-Za-z]{1})?)$`

I thought about making matching groups, since some groups such as the `(a)` groups before and after the numbers are the same, to shorten it. How would you shorten this regex?

Comment: In what language/regex environment are you using this?

Comment: Both Javascript and Ruby.

Comment: The Wikipedia page no longer gives this format (and I suspect it is wrong too, as flight numbers/codes do not need their numeric part to be padded out to 4 digits. Finding an official source is not easy though. Ah, here we go http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airline_codes xx(a)n(n)(n)(n)(a) - all characters in brackets are optional.

Comment: Be aware that the initial XX in a flight designator (aka flight code) can be aa, aN or Na, but never NN. i.e. it must contain at least one letter. My regex for XX is `([a-z][a-z]|[a-z][0-9]|[0-9][a-z])`, which I am using successfully in production (with the case-insensitive option set).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this in both Javascript and Ruby:

```
/^([^\W_]{2}[a-z]?)?(\d{4})[a-z]?$/i
```

The flag `i` for case insensitivity, and you still can get the numbers. The whole flight code is in the first element of the array, the numbers in the second element.

Since `[^\W]` is equivalent to `\w` i.e. `[a-z0-9_]` if you don't count foreign characters, using `[^\W_]` will mean only `[a-z0-9]` ignoring foreign characters.

Comment: I tried your regex in [Regexpal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E(%5B%5E%5CW_%5D%7B2%7D%5Ba-z%5D)%3F(%5Cd%7B4%7D)%5Ba-z%5D%3F%24&input=AA1334%0A1234%0AAAL1234z%0AAA12345) but it didn't work for anything other than the flight number.

Comment: @JoshuaSmock You have to check the case insensitivity

Comment: @JoshuaSmock I thought you meant that the AA(a) was optional in whole. Edited to this: [link](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gim&regex=%5E(%5B%5E%5CW_%5D%7B2%7D%5Ba-z%5D%3F)%3F(%5Cd%7B4%7D)%5Ba-z%5D%3F%24&input=AA1334%0A1234%0AAAL1234z%0AAA12345)

Comment: @JoshuaSmock For next time, I think that it'll be better if you put samples to accept and reject. Avoids misunderstandings :)

Comment: Yeah, sorry! I realized I wasn't as clear in my question as I should have been... sorry for the misunderstanding. But your regex works in the updated link, thanks!

Comment: Also your regex does work in both Ruby and Javascript, so you can update the question to reflect that.

Comment: @JoshuaSmock Thanks for confirming :)